# JPA criteria Api using group by and having clause

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have one entity lets say Devices which has a element collection of type MAP

```
class Device{
BigDecimal id;
@ElementCollection
MAP<String, String> properties;
...... 
}
```

I need to write a query to retrieve all the devices that match a set of given properties. I wrote the following JPA query using criteria API.

```
{
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Device> deviceQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Device.class);
Root<Device> device = deviceQuery.from(Device.class);
deviceQuery.select(device);

List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

if(!properties.isEmpty()){
 MapJoin<Device, String, String > propertyJoin =device.joinMap("deviceProperties",JoinType.INNER);
 Expression<BigDecimal> id = device.get(LocationConstants.ID);
 for(Map.Entry<String,String> property : properties.entrySet()){
   String key = property.getKey();
   String value = property.getValue();
   criteria.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(propertyJoin.key(), key),
   criteriaBuilder.equal(propertyJoin.value(), value)));
 }
 deviceQuery.groupBy(id);
 deviceQuery.having(criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.count(id), properties.size()));
 }
 deviceQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.or(criteria.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
}
```

But this returns a list of devices with duplicate values that match any of the subset of input properties given to the query .
On looking at the query formed the groupby and having clause were missing from the final query logged. Any idea why is this happening or what blunder of a mistake i have made in the code. Thanks here is the final query

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.DEVICE_TYPE, t1.CREATEDBY, t1.CREATEDON, t1.DESCRIPTION, t1.MODIFIEDBY, t1.MODIFIEDON, t1.NAME, t1.ID1, t1.ID2, t1.ID3, t1.STATUS, t1.INSTANCE, t1.NAMESPACE, t1.URL, t1.MAJOR, t1.MINOR, t1."UID" 
FROM LOC_DEVICE_PROPERTY t0, LOC_DEVICE t1 
WHERE ((((((t0.PROPERTY_KEY = ?) AND (t0.PROPERTY_VALUE = ?)) 
OR ((t0.PROPERTY_KEY = ?) AND (t0.PROPERTY_VALUE = ?))) 
OR ((t0.PROPERTY_KEY = ?) AND (t0.PROPERTY_VALUE = ?))) 
OR ((t0.PROPERTY_KEY = ?) AND (t0.PROPERTY_VALUE = ?))) 
AND (t0.Device_ID = t1.ID)) 
ORDER BY t1.ID ASC

[[bind => [8 parameters bound]]]
```

Comment: raise a bug with your JPA provider if it is missing off the GROUP BY, HAVING. Maybe try setting the where before the groupBy/having?

Comment: facing the same issue even after moving where clause statement above groupBy and having

Comment: presumably this is EclipseLink (based on the SQL generated, but then you still haven't said which one is used) so look at upgrading it to a recent version or report a bug with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work after struggling for two weeks. The solution was simple but finally thought of it after reading JPA SPECIFICATION here
http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html

The problem is the coloumn name that is in the groupBy should also be passed in the select clause. ID in my case should be mentioned JPA criteria API does not pick it up from Devices even though Devices is a member of Device class.